# Using Mail.dll with Microsoft Exchange Imap version 4

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

I am using [mail.dll](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) for reading emails. Earlier I was reading the emails from a gmail account and every thing was working alright. Now I need to move the application to another server and read mail from microsoft exchange.Below is the code that I am using

```
using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
   imap.Connect("server-name", port number);
   imap.Login("username", "password");
   imap.SelectInbox();
   List<long> uids = imap.Search(Flag.Seen);

   if (uids.Count > 0)
   {
       string eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uids[0]);
       IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(eml);
       imap.GetMessageByUID(uids[0]);
       lbResponse.Text = email.Subject;
   }
    else
    {
       lbResponse.Text = "No mails found";
     }
  imap.Close();
}
```

I have verified the port and server by using telnet and it is correct. But I get the "Unable to read data from the transport connection. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond  " error. Please help.

Comment: What port are you using? Which line rises the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that IMAP is enabled on your Exchange server:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124489.aspx

Also consider using:

```
imap.Search(Flag.Seen)
```

*SearchFlag* is obsolete in the latest version: http://www.limilabs.com/mail